# Unable to login to Zeppelin using the Zepl credentials

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to use Zepl, please help
I followed the documentation and added the following lines to 
zeppelin-env.sh

```
export ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_STORAGE="org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GitNotebookRepo, org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.zeppelinhub.ZeppelinHubRepo"
export ZEPPELINHUB_API_ADDRESS="https://www.zepl.com"
export ZEPPELINHUB_API_TOKEN=""
```

and to shiro.ini

```
zeppelinHubRealm = org.apache.zeppelin.realm.ZeppelinHubRealm
zeppelinHubRealm.zeppelinhubUrl = https://www.zepl.com
securityManager.realms = $zeppelinHubRealm
```

started the ZeppelinServer and Created account in zepl.

But unable to login to Zeppelin using the Zepl credentials.

Comment: which version of Zeppelin are you using?

Comment: Hi Khalid, 
Thank you for replying. I am using Zeppelin 0.7.1.
My log file has the following Error

ERROR [2017-10-27 16:26:28,334] ({qtp1286783232-18} LoginRestApi.java[postLogin]:98) - Exception in login:
org.apache.shiro.authc.UnknownAccountException: Realm [org.apache.shiro.realm.text.IniRealm@667bfaaf] was unable to find account data for the submitted AuthenticationToken [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - shylaja, rememberMe=false].
at org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator.doSingleRealmAuthentication(ModularRealmAuthenticator.java:184)

Comment: looks like your PAM authentication is also enabled and it tries to use it. Do you assign anywhere in your `shiro.ini` file the variable `securityManager.realms = ...` to some different values?

Comment: Hi Khalid, There was some issue with the configuration file not sure what. I did a new install and it is working now. Thanks